# Funcionamiento del Bcrypt Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, hash

vengo con una duda de seguridad.

```
public function prueba(){
    $password = '0000';
    return bcrypt($password);
}
```

Tengo esta funcion en Laravel, lo llamo directo desde una URL, estaba probando el encriptado de mis contraseñas. El problema, es que, cada que recargo la pagina, en lugar de devolverme un determinado hash, el hash cambia. Y no se porque.

```
hash1
$2y$10$d3WaO2SzDNPg8nX0W0oU8OeeLRrq62/TP8NyIjR7l/2gU26iPb.5C

hash2
$2y$10$/Xiyh7t3qltQ69DzW9RzOeR.S6mQ8THZHM5QTpyJu8Z27Z3MOLvLu

hash3
$2y$10$vJAMZpm3EOuOGrNSElvJGOoHv4NI5cOj7JFEF6lBPrg3ti0sZfMI.
```

Estoy haciendo esto porque me pidieron un archivo sql con los datos iniciales para arrancar el sitio. Ya saben, un Admin inicial y ciertas tablas mas que deben ser cargadas con datos extras. Mi problema es que queria guardar en la tabla Users los datos de usuario, poniendo como contraseña `0000` y un correo tipo `admin@mysite.com`

Por eso cree esa funcion para poder extraer el hash de 0000, pero cada que recargo la pagina me devuelve un hash diferente.

Comment: El hash es diferente cada vez que lo corres, pero almacena la misma información; cuando vas a utilizarlo, por ejemplo, al iniciar sesión, laravel "compara" el hash de la contraseña ingresa con el string de la contraseña guardada y si coincide, te permite hacer login

Comment: Entonces genera diferente hash pero son los mismos. Genial, muchas gracias.